# JavaScript, change TextField color based on ComoBox value

Tags: background-color, fill

I have a problem with a JavaScript coding to change TextField color with value.

I have a ComboBox to feed TextFeild with a value when it's Buy Order the TextField background color is changing to Green, with a Sell order the color is Red.

The JavaScript I have is working fine, but, I didn't like the coloring at all!!!

I would like to find a way to use RGB colors, can you help me that?

```
function test()
{
var s = this.getField("Order01");
    if(!event.willCommit)
    {
        if (event.change == "Sell") 
    {
      this.resetForm(s);
          s.fillColor = color.red;
      s.value = "Sell Order";

    }
    else if (event.change =="Buy")
    {
      this.resetForm(s);
          s.fillColor = color.green;
      s.value = "Buy Order";

    }
              else if (event.change=="Transaction")
    {
      this.resetForm(s);
          s.fillColor = color.transparent;
      s.value = " ";
    }
     }
}
```

Comment: rgb colors are accepted in CSS as "rgb(r,g,b)". They also work in javascript.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan,  I've tried to following s.colorfill = "rgb(155, 102, 102)"; and s.color = "rgb(155, 100, 210)"; but it's not working

Comment: Don't use s.colorfill. To set css properties use ```s.style.fill```, ```s.style.color```, ```s.style.backgroundColor```or ```s.style.fillcolor```depending on your element